# WAMP and mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002)?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, wamp

I upgraded from **Windows 7** to **Windows 10** recently, and installed **WAMP**.
This is my first time working with WAMP.

I am getting following error message in one of my **Codeigniter** project I was working in windows 7 setup and I don't know what to make of it. The page keeps on loading and loading and then fails with the error message.

> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond.

Further done the page this is the message I get :

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

The **hostname**, **username**, **password** and **database** are correct.

But if I change **dbdriver** to **mysql** from **mysqli** then **the website loads**, but with the following error.

> Message: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will
>   be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

**What am I doing wrong ?**

Note: Oh and yes, I can access **phpmyadmin**

Comment: Have you checked that PHP's `mysqli.default_socket` is correct (in php.ini)?

Comment: @Tristan It is blank.

Comment: That's probably fine, it just means it will use the default. Check that there is no semicolon before `extension=php_mysqli.dll` in your php.ini file

Comment: @Tristan no semicolon.

Comment: Another check: if your connecting on `localhost`, check your `hosts` file `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\host` for `127.0.0.1  localhost`

Comment: @Tristan I did change the host file while creating virtual hosts. Here is how it looks now : 127.0.0.1       localhost
::1 localhost

127.0.0.1       dbninja
::1 dbninja

127.0.0.1       Something
::1 Something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97248/discussion-between-tristan-and-studentx).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysqli on WAMP, error - connection attempt failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325842/mysqli-on-wamp-error-connection-attempt-failed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out and I hope the solution will help someone facing the same problem as me.

Since my server was running slow, I was searching for solutions, I tried a lot of thing but nothing worked, then I changed host name for the database connection from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and it worked. This change made **mysqli work** and it made my **server a lot faster**